# Match Subject elements of a parsed SSL Certificate using regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm parsing SSL Certificates using `openssl_x509_parse`.

The name element of the array produces the following type string which contains the certificate subject information.

```
[name] = /serialNumber=wsZ0axJazQw/eeFdiFKbpoVW/7uORUSh/OU=GT20702350/OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)13/OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R)/CN=mail.example.com
```

How could I extract the parts from this string? I'm trying to generate a list using PHP e.g.

```
serialNumber = wsZ0axJazQw/eeFdiFKbpoVW/7uORUSh
OU = GT20702350
OU = See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)13
OU = Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R)
CN = mail.example.com
```

I'm still learning how regex's work (they really do give me a headache!), but am struggling with this one, as I'm not sure how to deal with the forward slashes present in some of the 'value' fields of the string.

I've come up with:

```
([^/]([a-zA-Z0-9]*)[=]([a-zA-Z0-9\s+\.\-\(\)]*)[^/])
```

So far (http://www.rexfiddle.net/4atGGqG)

As you can see it's very basic, i.e. it doesn't deal with the forward slashes.

How can I 'fix' this?

On a side note, is there a better way (than what I've done) to deal with special characters in the 'value fields' other than an escaped list of each possible one ('`\.\-\(\)`')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex(using negative lookahead) should work -

```
\/([a-zA-Z]+?=(?:(?!\/[a-zA-Z]+?=.*?).)*)
```

You can test it and breakdown the regex [Here](https://regex101.com/r/uA7wX2/19)

Testing it-

```
$name = "/serialNumber=wsZ0axJazQw/eeFdiFKbpoVW/7uORUSh/OU=GT20702350/OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)13/OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R)/CN=mail.example.com";
$regex = "/\/([a-zA-Z]+?=(?:(?!\/[a-zA-Z]+?=.*?).)*)/";
if(preg_match_all($regex, $name, $matches)){
    var_dump($matches[1]);
}
/**
    OUTPUT
**/
array
  0 => string 'serialNumber=wsZ0axJazQw/eeFdiFKbpoVW/7uORUSh' (length=45)
  1 => string 'OU=GT20702350' (length=13)
  2 => string 'OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)13' (length=43)
  3 => string 'OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R)' (length=41)
  4 => string 'CN=mail.example.com' (length=19)
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly. Thanks for the link, appreciate the added explanation too.

Comment: How is this working? If I go to the link with the regex it says "Your regular expression does not match the subject string."

Comment: @Tranquilized It's been 9 years since this was posted. Most likely the regex101 site might have changed a few things (it defaulted to python, someone might've updated the example, site changed etc.) I've updated the link to make it work for the current example.